# Is coin a mana?

Tags: money, talmud-bavli, bava-metzia

The gemara ([Bava Metzia 47a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=47&format=pdf)) quotes a statement, and tries to figure out which opinions are (in)compatible with this statement:

> אמר רב ששת בריה דרב אידי כמאן כתבינן האידנא במנא דכשר למקניא ביה במנא
>   לאפוקי מדרב ששת דאמר קונין בפירות [...] ‏
>
> R. Shesheth, the son of R. Iddi, said: In accordance with whom do we
>   write nowadays, ‘with a utensil that is fit for acquiring possession
>   therewith’? ‘With a utensil’ — that rejects the view of R. Shesheth, who maintains: A title may be effected by means of produce. [...]

(*Soncino translation*)

On the next page ([47b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=47b&format=pdf)), the discussion continues:

> .ביה רב פפא אמר למעוטי מטבע
>
> ‘Therewith’ — R. Papa said: It is to exclude coins.

Does this discussion imply that a coin is a "מנא?" If coins are *not* utensils, shouldn't they have been previously excluded from the word "מנא"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discuss for Kinyan Chalipin.
The question is about the Hava Amina that entails an additional teaching to exclude the possibility of Chalipin with coin.

#### The answer can be found in Kesef Mishne

**Introduction:** The rationale is that when the Gemara says mana, the definition is a not-fruit. So coin may be a mana in this sense. And further the Gemara found two different versions of the statements of Rav Papa. the first is that coin is not equivalent to utensils, and the second says that coin is equivalent to utensils in matter of Chalipin (Not in Matter of hilchot Shabbat or hilchot Tum'at Kelim).
See bellow a snippet of Kesef Mishne *Sefer Kinyan, Hilchot Mechira, chapter 5, Halacha 6*, annotated: The whole text is [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=89275&rid=12515)

> ואמרו בגמרא במנא לאפוקי ממ"ד קונין בפירות ביה למעוטי מטבע **‏   שכיון שאמרו במנא נתמעטו בין מטבע בין שאר דברים דלא הוו כלי וביה למה לי למעוטי מטבע**‏?‏‏ 
> ‏ 
> **‏ י"ל דכל מילי מיקרו כלי לבד מפירות לפי שאין דומים כלל לנעל שאין משתמשים בהם בשום מלאכה ונרקבין ונפסדין במעט זמן ואין מתקיימין כנעל** ‏ ‏‏ ומטבע כעין נעל הוא דראוי להשתמש בו לתלותו בצואר הבנות ולשקול בו משקלותיו ואינו נרקב [...] ‏

---

> And it is said in the *gemara*, "A utensil" to exclude the opinion
>   that holds that one can effect a *chalipin* with fruit, and
>   "therewith" to exclude coins. **[One might ask] since it is said "with
>   a utensil," that should exclude both coins as well as anything else
>   that is not a vessel, and why do we need "therewith" to exclude coin?**
>
> **One could answer that anything can be called a vessel besides for
>   fruit, because they are not at all similar to a shoe [see explanation
>   below], because they cannot be used for any labor. Additionally, they
>   rot and are lost after a short time and do not last like a shoe.** And
>   a coin is like a shoe because one can use it for [some form of] work,
>   e.g. to hang it from the necklace of young girls, or to weigh things
>   with it, and it doesn't rot [...]

(*free translation*)

The reason we care so much about comparing the object of *chalipin* to a shoe is because the inverse opinion of the one that was excluded from "mana" (Rav Nachman) holds that because the source of *chalipin* is "ושלף איש נעלו" ([Rus 4:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16456#v=7)), *chalipin* only works with something that is "similar to a shoe," in other words, a "kli."